# Using flatMap inside another observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have this function:

```
public getAssignedOrganizations() : Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.settings.backend.assignedOrganizations)
        .flatMap((org) => {
            return this.http
                .get(this.settings.backend.warehousesByOrg + org.organization_id)
                .map((res: any) => res.json());
        })
        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server error'));
}
```

`org` will return an array of objects so `flatMap` won't understand the parameter. How can I iterate through the response of the first `HTTP` request (`org`) so I can call the second `HTTP`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First do a map on your array, to map each element on the proper request. You will get an observable of observables (the latter being each request result). You can then flatMap this stream of stream.

Comment: And BTW, it seems you're still using the deprecated Http service, so org is not an array. It's a Response. You're shooting yourself in the foot by using `any` everywhere.

Comment: Thanks! It's working.

Answer (score 0):

`map` operator will be chained next after `flatMap`

```
public getAssignedOrganizations() : Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.settings.backend.assignedOrganizations)
                  .flatMap((org) => {
                      return this.http.get(this.settings.backend.warehousesByOrg + org.organization_id)
                  })
                  .map((res: any) => res.json());                    
                  .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server error'));
}
```